# WebView (not WKWebView) calling Localized HTML file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

A Mac app requires that a HTML file be called in a WebView (the legacy type, not the newer WKWebView) in a localized form to present the user with some content.

As I side note, I realize that WebView should not be used today, and WKWebView is preferred, however this is a legacy app that currently needs support.

I've used a similar method for the iOS version, however it does not seem to be working. The HTML files are simply called "Term.HTML" and are placed in each localization folder alongside the localized string and all other localized content. This is the code I tried to use:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:NSLocalizedString(@"fileTerm", nil) ofType:@"html"];
htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[termsView takeStringURLFrom:htmlString];
```

Where my localized strings file each contain a line that says:

```
"fileTerm" = "Term";
```

This is what links the declaration of the first line to the actual file. It works in iOS. However, when running the app and the view containing the WebView attempt to the run, XCode will automatically create a breakpoint on the third line when I actually attempt to give the HTML file to "termsView" which is my WebView. After skipping this breakpoint, and forcing the app to run, the whole view containing the WebView will simply not appear. I would be thankful if anyone knew why this was or if there was a better way to do this? Thank you everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure why you use 'NSLocalizedString' for the file name, this seems unnecessary to me. But to figure out the issue, when you hit the breakpoint, what do you see in htmlFile and htmlString?

Comment: The reason for this is because I need to call a different HTML file depending on the language the device is set in to display it properly localized. Is there another method to do this?

Comment: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Term" ofType:@"html"]` will search the .lproj folder, so you just need to put the english in en.lproj/Term.html, german in de.lproj/Term.html and so on.

Answer (score 1):

may be someone needs in **SWift**: I solved this problem with saving 3 html file for every language, and then in ViewController class checked current  app language. And called up the html file for current language

```
func loadHtmlFile() {
    let preferredLanguage = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0]
    if preferredLanguage == "kz" {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "aboutUs_kz", withExtension:"html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    if preferredLanguage == "ru" {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "aboutUs_ru", withExtension:"html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
    if preferredLanguage == "en" {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "aboutUs_en", withExtension:"html")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

in  viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        loadHtmlFile()
}
```